# C# List.Insert misses some indexes

Tags: c#, list, insert

I have a `List<string>` called `stringList`. I was trying to insert into the list some strings. First I used for loop to generate "empty places" for my content.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            stringList.Add(null);
        }
```

Then I used `stringlist.Insert(index, element)` to insert an element into the List at the specified index. Next I wanted to see if every element was properly read.

This is my `stringList`:

[image: list]

Every element is properly read, but there are three indexes missed. At 3rd index should be what is at 6th, at 4th -> 7th and so on.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

This is fragment of code (for index 3, 4, 5), where the program reads elements and inserts it into the list.

```
case "yweather:wind":

stringList.Insert(3, reader["speed"]);//3
break;

case "yweather:atmosphere":

stringList.Insert(4, reader["pressure"]);//4
stringList.Insert(5, reader["rising"]);//5
stringList.Insert(6, reader["humidity"]);//6

break;
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`List.Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) will add an element to the list at the given index **and shift all the following elements**.

You probably just want to set a given index, as you're inserting `null` elements. If so, use this syntax instead:

```
stringList[3] = reader["speed"]; // etc
```

But as you know the capacity you want up front, it'd be better to just use a simple array, so you don't have to initialize a list with empty items:

```
var stringList = new string[60];
```

And then use the same syntax (`stringList[i] = whatever;`) to populate it.

If you have to use a `List<T>` (eg if you're adding other elements later on), then at least use the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx) that lets you preallocate some space up front:

```
var stringList = new List<string>(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because method Insert() really 'inserts' element. Let me explain..

Suppose that below is a list;

1 2 3

if you insert element 4 in 2, it results like this;

1 2 4 3

This is your mistake.